# How to order table by date column on 2 other joined tables in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have the following tables:

```
table_1
id      | table_2_id |  table_3_id | table_1_specific_columns
1       | null       | 1           |
2       | 1          | null        |
...
```

and:

```
table_2
id      | table_2_specific_columns| date
1       | blabla                  | 01-01-1990
2       | bababa                  | 02-02-1992
...
```

and:

```
table_3
id      | table_3_specific_columns| date
1       | blabla                  | 01-01-1991
2       | bababa                  | 02-02-1989
...
```

The database is PostgreSQL

How to order table_1 by date column on table_2 and table_3 joined tables in Laravel?

Can this be done using Eloquent?

Edit: the expected result, if it can be done using eloquent, is a Collection of table_1 model with table_2 and table_3 relations ordered by the date column in table_2 and table_3

Edit2:

Expected result for asc ordering of table_1. The date column is added for quick reference, not required.

```
id      | table_2_id |  table_3_id           | date
1       | null       | 2                     | 02-02-1989
2       | 1          | null                  | 01-01-1990
1       | null       | 1                     | 01-01-1991
2       | 2          | null                  | 02-02-1992
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: @jarlh added expected result

Comment: Specify, not describe.

Comment: @jarlh added specific example of result after ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've shared you either have a table_2 or table_3 relationship (if any) so you could do:

```
DB::table('table_1')
    ->leftJoin('table_2', 'table_1.table_2_id','table_2.id')
    ->leftJoin('table_3', 'table_1.table_3_id','table_3.id')
    ->select('table_1.*')
    ->orderByRaw('COALESCE(table_2.date, table_3.date)');
```

Note: If a row relates to both table 2 and table 3 the order is given by table_2 only

The downside here is that you'll also include any rows of `table_1` which don't relate to anything. You could omit those by adding `->whereNotNull('table_2.id')->orWhereNotNull('table_3.id')`

If you have a model you can modify the above to use e.g. `Table1::leftJoin....` instead of using `DB::table` in this case `select('table_1.*')` becomes even more important to not add the wrong values in the model objects

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use  syntax

> [orderByRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods)

So your code will be similar to :

```
Table::orderByRaw("column DESC, column2 ASC")->get();
```